# Problem compiling Lyx document - "you are using at least one layout intended for the title after using non-title layouts"

Tags: errors, lyx, compiling, layout

I am trying to compile a Lyx document (written in Hebrew, if it matters), and when I try to compile I get the following message:
[image]

And after a while of trying to compile it puts out the following error:
[image]

And the compiled PDF cannot be opened.

There are no local layouts or preambles for the file. Even if I delete all of the text in the file and compile something empty, it still does not compile (so there is no minimal working example).

I tried exporting the Lyx to a Latex file and compiling it. I then get the following error:

"Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined (inputenc) in inputencoding 'cp1255'.

Did anybody ever come across this error and has an idea on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello GSofer, there is not enough information to answer your question. It would be helpful if you will add a MWE.

Comment: @UdiFogiel As I said, even when I delete everything in the file, it still does not compile. So I am not sure what a MWE should look like.

Comment: A Lyx file is a text file, so you can open it with any text editor and copy it's content to the post. The shorter the file the better, but post one that still issue the error when compiling.